# Delete a Line which contains 1,2,3 .. random word

Tags: regex, notepad++

For example, if I have a text file that contains the following :
I want to delete whole line for which contains only 1 word

Before:

```
Text text text
text text text
text
text text
```

After:

```
Text text text
text text text

text text
```

Which regex I should use in Notepad++ to delete the unwanted lines?

Comment: This is not related to programming.

Comment: Show us your efforts.

Comment: I have 100 000 lines text

Comment: @AndrásElKoulali The regex tag makes it a programming question. But the OP needs to show their effort(s) and then ask questions

Comment: @AndrásElKoulali This is related to regex, a type of programming, though the OP should show us what he's tried.

Comment: @Sladerx Do you use Windows or Unix?

Comment: Windows i usually work with Notepad++

Comment: What is a "word" for you? Only alphabetics? Alphanumerics? Word character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`? Alphanumerics with non latin characters? Everything that is not a space or punctuation? Something else?

Comment: all symbols except spaces

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete lines containing only a single word with no surrounding whitespace, then try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^\S+$
Replace: (empty string)
```

This assumes that a "word" is defined as any continuous collection of one or more non whitespace characters.  If you wanted to target only words consisting of word characters, then use `^\w+$`.  To take into account leading and trailing whitespace, you could use `^\s*\S+\s*$`.

### Demo

Comment: @CinCout No, it won't, because my pattern uses `^` and `$` anchors.  Check the demo, you are mistaken.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Where did you see the OP mention _Notepad_?  It clearly mentioned NPP, which absolutely does use `^` and `$` to represent the start and end of every line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going through it one line at a time, `\w\s+\w` might be of use. It detects if there is a word, space, and a word.

Comment: The OP's requirement is to detect a _single_ word on a given line, not two of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(\A|\r\n)\S+(\Z|\r\n)`

Explanation:

`\A` - anchor: beginning of an inpit

`\r\n` - carriage return and newline characters (indicating new line)

`\Z` - anchor: end of an inpit

`\S+` - match one or more characters other from white space

Replace it with `\r\n`

Comment: How do you know the OP is using Windows `\r\n` line endings?  What about Unix?